# How can I use a UIWebview to load content from a asp.net website dynamically loading .mp4 video and get the video to play?

Tags: uiwebview

I have a client that has a website. The website current allows users to login and search for and play .mp4 video. The list of playlist is created dynamically where values are stored in a sql server 2008 database. My client's site is already built for smartphone utilization and did not want to recreate an iphone app. Besides it would mean loading thousands of video. Instead I thought I would use the UIWebview to load the website. This seemed to work well. However, when you try to click on and play video within the UIWebview nothing happens. This is not the case if we launch the mobile website within the apple mobile safari browser. The vide plays by kicking off in the iPhone video player. Is there any way to accomplish this same functionality with a uiwebview? Any guidance or help is appreciated.

Comment: Just wanted to add I am already using the video tag with html5 and the JW Player on the mobile web side of the application. I have seen many questions asked about this but none seem to pertain to using video that is dynamically generate or pulled from a database. I see answers that sugest using a direct link to the video. That wouldn't be an option for this client.

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView will play video using `<video>` if everything is set up correctly, either remote files or local files will work (if they are the correct format).

What does your video tag look like? In particular your src.

If you want to, for example, play an inline video the html5 for that would be something like

```
<video id="theVideo" controls width="280" height="160" src="yourVideo.mp4"  webkit-playsinline></video>
```

And it would be necessary in the UIWebView to set this line

> self.webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;

Or you can also explicitly load the media player, but doing everything in HTML5 is neat and tidy and easy.

Comment: My video tag is .mp4. Thanks.

Comment: I mean what does your html5 <video> tag content look like that you mention in your comment.